# how to pass a value from node/express app to an AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm developing an app based on mean.js boiler plate.

In one of my Angular controllers, I need to "know" whether the app is running in dev, test, or prod.

When the hosting Node app starts, this is indicated via the NODE_ENV environment variable, so Node knows where its running.

How do I pass this knowledge onto the Angular part of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this knowledge on your backend, why not make an endpoint you can call in an AngularJS `run` method. While I do not know the details of your backend implementation, surely you can return a variable which represents this information. You can simply craft something like the following...

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    $http.get('/yourEndoint').success(function(response) {
        $rootScope.whereAmI = response.whereAmI;
    });
}]);
```

Where `wereAmI` is some value you return from your backend and return to this call. If you place it on `$rootScope`, all other `$scope`'s will inherit this value so you'll have knoweldege of "where you're at" app wide.

For more info on the `run` function, check out the [AngularJS module docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run
>   block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It
>   is executed after all of the services have been configured and the
>   injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is
>   hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated
>   modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use gulp/grunt build task to select the requested `config.js` file (ie. `production.config.js`). Then you can use something like [npm args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/args) to set an `--env=production` or `--env=development` variable when running your build task, which then is used by the gulp/grunt task to grab the requested config file.

Then your actual config file will just be an `angular.constant(...)` component with settings to use for your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I picked the other one as an answer, as it fits a bit more naturally with the other elements of my flow (at least for now)